# Why can't I install two react native apps that copied from the same project folder

Tags: android, react-native

I created react native (project A). I generated a apk file and installed it on my android phone.

Then, I copied the (project A) folder and develop (project B) with a different name, icon and features in that folder. And, I generated apk file. But I can't install (project B) while (project A) is installed on my phone.

Why? Please...

Comment: If my answer was helpful and was able to resolve your issue, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **change the package name** of the copied application to some other name.

Say **project A** package name is "**com.projectA.app**"

Rename **project B**'s package name to "**com.projectB.app**"

This should fix the problem. Do a find of "com.projectA.app" in your whole app folder, that should help you more.

Or you can use a plugin to do it for you. "[react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)" I haven't personally used it but seems to get the job done.